# Transaction fails without error code

Tags: transactions, testnet

I'm playing with the Stellar java SDK and I'm trying to send to send some Lumens from a fully funded account to an other account on the testnet.

Once the transaction is complete I get back a response with all the field being null expect the "extra" field which has all its field to null except the "envelopeXdr" which is equal to

> AAAAAPQl3
>   LgGzmS98AbidI2Pf5iG6/Y5JjjA8qGFcCFlAnlAAAAZABnH7IAAAABAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAABAAAAACzKntDKAeTf87abUrrUsJAEPQPEfc7EEcKXsrnaAG2RAAAAAAAAAAAGjneAAAAAAAAAAAGFlAnlAAAAQDYKf5r5BqDRGHm
>   9K0zTfPQ0nSKMZxwKblhnW/GHV1gbXcm4NOfmBNBowjW9xHtY2p9
>   4MBPLRJUjYVeR2t3Qw=

How can I know what went wrong ?

**EDIT:**

Code:

```
        Network.useTestNetwork();
        Server server = new Server("https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org");
        KeyPair source = KeyPar.fromSecredSeed("...")
        KeyPair destination = KeyPair.fromAccountId("...");
        AccountResponse sourceAccount = server.accounts().account(source);
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction.Builder(sourceAccount)
            .addOperation(new PaymentOperation.Builder(destination, new AssetTypeNative(), "1000").build())
            .addMemo("")
            .build();
        transaction.sign(source);
        SubmitTransactionResponse response = server.submitTransaction(transaction);
```

I have taken the transcationXdr and input it in the Stellar laboratory to make a transaction and it worked....

This leads to the Java sdk having an issue when making the request, maybe some issue in the way it sets the "tx" in the post params

**EDIT2**
Yes it was, I had modified the source and messed around the encoding

Comment: Is your envelopXdr valid? Seems there are some new line

Comment: What API endpoint / SDK method are you using to submit the transaction?

Comment: If the xdr works with laboratory, it means that problem is related to java sdk. Better for you to open a detailed issue on github https://github.com/stellar/java-stellar-sdk/issues

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Need to remove newline from your posted xdr

Using xdr viewer on stellar laboratory, your transaction result success

Ps: select PaymentResult as XDR type

Check [here](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?input=AAAAAPQl3LgGzmS98AbidI2Pf5iG6%2FY5JjjA8qGFcCFlAnlAAAAZABnH7IAAAABAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAABAAAAACzKntDKAeTf87abUrrUsJAEPQPEfc7EEcKXsrnaAG2RAAAAAAAAAAAGjneAAAAAAAAAAAGFlAnlAAAAQDYKf5r5BqDRGHm9K0zTfPQ0nSKMZxwKblhnW%2FGHV1gbXcm4NOfmBNBowjW9xHtY2p94MBPLRJUjYVeR2t3Qw%3D&type=PaymentResult&network=test)

Comment: That is odd though.. because the account still has a balance of 10'000 and the response.isSuccess is false